# Find Amazon ASIN in an API?

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to find the Amazon ASIN from an API call, which I'll give some parameters.
Example:
Google search for: `site:amazon.com Top Gun Tom Cruise` --> ASIN: B001K3K5MO.

Explanation:
I'm telling the Google search to only focus on sites containing `amazon.com` and giving it the keywords: Top Gun Tom Cruise. In this case the first link is the correct one. Now this ASIN can be scraped from the Amazon url and thus I can make a Python script to find the ASIN. However, if I mistype some keywords or it can't find the correct version, Google is still going to find another product and scraping that ASIN will result in a wrong ASIN.

Now there's an Amazon API that uses the ASIN to find details about the product ([This site uses it](https://amazon-asin.com/asincheck/?product_id=B001K3K5MO#hl-product-detail)), but I'd like to do the exact opposite. So finding the ASIN by giving it keywords. I could even specify keywords into `title: Top Gun` and `cast: Tom Cruise` or something along those lines.
Looking forward to any reply!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon offers [Product Advertising API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/) using which you can search, in specific you can use [SearchItems](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/search-items.html) to search with keywords and it returns results with resources selected. One of the resources is [Parent ASIN](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/parent-asin.html) which contains the Parent ASIN number. You can also search for child ASIN numbers (check the link of ParentASIN for more details).

It is obvious that as you are searching by keywords there would be multiple results returned so you would have to filter and find the best matching result.

**Note:** There are [prerequisites/registration](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/register-for-pa-api.html) to use the API, it is not open for all.